# React-native: Looks like you installed react-native globally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install

There appears to be a bug with react-native, when it is installed globally. I need it to execute properly without seeing this error:

```
$ react-native run-ios
Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Solutions posted on other forums didn't work for me, I don't see reason why this doesn't work.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-svgkit",
  "version": "0.2.2",
  "main": "Svg.js",
  "description": "A <Svg /> element for react-native that renders Svg images using SVGKit",
  "author": "Brent Vatne <brentvatne@gmail.com> (https://github.com/brentvatne)",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "15.1.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native": ">=0.4.4",
    "react-native-cli": "^0.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^3.5.5",
    "jsdom-jscore": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:brentvatne/react-native-svgkit.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this command via npm ?

Comment: Yes, it's in the standard global location `/usr/local/bin/react-native`

Comment: Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: react-native-svgkit is an old project not under development and not supported on latest versions of react-native. Are you interested in an svg library or do you want to upgrade and maintain that library?

Comment: I am interested not in using the library itself, but a library that brings SVG to latest react-native.

Comment: I get same problem with react-natie run-android

Answer (score 6):

Use this in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android"
}
```

instead of

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android"
 }
```

Comment: This worked! But can you tell me what is the absolute path?

Answer (score 3):

In my case this problem was because because npm was installed using homebrew. A description of this problem and how to fix it can be found at on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689).  In summary the required fix is to uninstall all your npm globably installed packages, uninstall node, then reinstall node, and reinstall npm without brew.

```
npm list -g --depth=0 # to list all your globally installed packages
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

and then, you have to reinstall all your npm packages that were installed globally using `npm install -g <package_name>`.

Unfortunately, when I rebooted my machine, the same problem re-occured. My current work around is to follow the suggestion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4515) i.e

```
npm install --save-dev react-native-cli
```

Any explanation as to what is going on is welcome.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev react-native-cli` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue cloning a repo using react-native^0.17.0 which is about 8 years old. I changed the version to the latest in package.json, installed my packages and the started the dev-client as expected.

Answer (score -2):

For some reason I **removed all dependencies from** **package.json** file and install them manually

```
yarn add react-native redux
```

and rest of them and it worked for me,
I figured out the issue was with versions of installed packages.

Comment: what redux doing here?